# What exactly is the use of defining level in the top-most scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, winston

I was just going through the Winston logger [usage guide](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#usage) and came across the following usage:

```
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  format: winston.format.json(),
  defaultMeta: { service: 'user-service' },
  transports: [
    //
    // - Write all logs with importance level of `error` or less to `error.log`
    // - Write all logs with importance level of `info` or less to `combined.log`
    //
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' }),
  ],
});
```

What is the use of defining `level: 'info',` if you're going to have `level: 'error'`? Or is it the case that the latter is overriding `level: 'info',`, because according to [the docs](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#creating-your-own-logger) the outer `level` does the following:

> Log only if [`info.level`](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#streams-objectmode-and-info-objects) is less than or equal to this level

So what exactly is the use of defining `level` in the top-most scope?

Comment: `info` is the threshold for this logger instance and `error` only for the specific error.log transport. If `info` would be `error`, `combined.log` would only log errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you're setting up the Winston logger so that it *listens* for all messages at the `info` level or below (with those log levels conforming to the universal rfc5424 set of levels, [explained on page 11](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424)). We're not saying what to actually do with that data yet, we're just telling it to ignore anything that's less sever than `info`.

You can define levels at the top level as well as at the level of each transport, so basically in your example if you defined any transport eg.

```
new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' }),
```

Then we set up individual log transporters to work with that data, by transporting it somewhere. But, you don't necessarily want to point the same firehose at all your destiations, so in this case we have two "transport to file" entries, one that logs only error-or-more-severe to a file called `error.log`, and one that logs "everything that Winston is set to listen to" to a file called `combined.log` (and because we configured it for "info or more severe", that file will never contain `debug` or `silly` messages, because that's not going to be in the data that this Winston logger was set up to see)

Comment: heavyly edited your answer hope you don't mind , reason being `answers the critical questions of does transport level override outer most level and also what does level at transport and both top level log and exclude.`

Comment: Kinda do mind, yeah, since it already explained what was going on just fine, you removed the two step explanation, and of course, changed it to something I wouldn't write making it no longer my answer =)

Answer (score 1):

Like said in the docs you cited:

> winston allows you to define a level property on each transport which specifies the maximum level of messages that a transport should log

So from the levels shown above, for instance `debug` would log everything, `info` would log everything except `debug` or `crit` would log `emerg`, `alter` and `crit`

Furthermore, if not explicitly defined for the transport, the transport uses the same logging level as the defined default on the top level.

So for your given configuration, the default logging level is `info`, everything that is "less critical" than `info` is ignored by winston. Thus also the `combined.log` would have the same level, and will contain all log messages, except on level `debug`...

The second transport for the file `error.log` has explicitly defined the level as `error`, thus will only contain messages for levels `error, crit, alert, emerg`.

The purpose of that could for instance be, to have an explitic error log that only contains error messages, and one log that contains all messages ...